# Implement some insets in HTMLLabel but "drawTextinRect" get never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uiedgeinsets

I´m using HTMLLabel (https://github.com/nicklockwood/HTMLLabel) and i would like to implement some insets. So i wrote in the HTMLLabel.m file:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
 {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 5, 0, 5};
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

But the method never get called, any ideas why? Thanks for your help!

Comment: That would be a question for Nick Lockwood, wouldn't it? You're the one who chose to use third-party code; now you are stuck with its limitations. If you need a modification of what it does, figure out how it works and modify it under the hood, or write to Nick Lockwood with a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's because what this class is doing is illegal. For example, it overrides `drawRect:`, which you are not allowed to do for a UILabel. Moreover, it does this without calling `super`. So it has interfered with the normal workings of the underlying UILabel, and you are therefore unable to access those normal workings.

Looking at it in a more positive light: an HTMLLabel is not a label. It poses as a UILabel, in the sense that it is all wrapped up and access through a UILabel; but it doesn't use the UILabel to draw the text at all; it uses a helper view called an HTMLLayout. So from the underlying UILabel's point of view, nothing is actually happening. It doesn't consult you about drawing the text because it *doesn't* draw any text.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will try it another way!